# Как изменить URL записей Wordpress таким образом?

Tags: wordpress

каким образом можно сделать такой тип URL Для записей Wordpress
*site.ru/blog/nameArticle*

Проблема в том что если задать в настройках постоянных ссылок что то /blog/nameArticle - это работает но применяется ко всем типа записей( У меня еще 3 доп. Custom Post Type, а мне надо лишь для статьей ( что идут изначально ) )

Answer (score 1):

Можно через фильтры создать свои правила

Добавьте в functions.php

```
    add_filter('pre_post_link', 'change_post_link', 1, 3 );

    function change_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
        
        $post = get_post( $id );

        if( $post->post_type == 'post' )  {
            
            if ( is_object( $post ) ) {

                return '/blog'.$post_link;
            }     
        }
        return   $post_link ;
   }
   
   add_action('init', 'generated_rewrite_post_rules' ); 

   function generated_rewrite_post_rules() {
       
       add_rewrite_rule(
           '^blog/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
           'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[2]',
           'top'
       );
       
       flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
```